# Simple design choice?

Tags: c++, overloading, friend

Say I have a class with a `private data member n` and a `public get_n()` function.
When overloading the output operator for example, I can either use `get_n()` or make it a friend and use `n`.
Is there a 'best' choice? And if so, why?
Or is the difference going to be optimized away?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think a get_n() function is even noticable compared to the output itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already gotten a lot of somewhat-conflicting answers, so what you undoubtedly need is one more that contradicts nearly all of them.

From an efficiency viewpoint, it's unlikely to make any difference. A function that just returns a value will undoubtedly be generated inline unless you specifically prohibit that from happening by turning off *all* optimization.

That leaves only a question of what's preferable from a design viewpoint. At least IMO, it's *usually* preferable to *not* have a `get_n` in the first place. Once you remove that design problem, the question you asked just disappears: since there is no `get_n` to start with, you *can't* write other code to depend upon it.

That does still leave a small question of how you should do things though. This (of course) leads to more questions. In particular, what sort of thing does `n` represent? I realize you're probably giving a hypothetical example, but a good design (in this case) depends on knowing a little more about what `n` is and how it's used, as well as the type of which `n` is a member, and how *it* is intended to be used as well.

If `n` is a member of a leaf class, from which you expect no derivation, then you should probably use a friend function that writes `n` out directly:

```
class whatever { 
    int n;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, whatever const &w) { 
        return os << w.n;
    }
};
```

Simple, straightforward, and effective.

If, however, `n` is a member of something you expect to use (or be used) as a base class, then you usually want to use a "virtual virtual" function:

```
class whatever { 
    int n;

    virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) { 
        return os << n;
    }    

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, whatever const &w) { 
        return w.write(os);
    }
};
```

Note, however, that this assumes you're interested in writing out an entire object, and it just happens that at least in the current implementation, that means writing out the value of `n`.

As to why you should do things this way, there are a few simple principles I think should be followed:

1. Either make something *really* private, or make it public. A private member with public `get_n` (and, as often as not, public `set_n` as well) may be required for JavaBeans (for one example) but is still a really *bad* idea, and shows a *gross* misunderstanding of object orientation or encapsulation, not to mention producing downright ugly code.
2. Tell, don't ask. A public `get_n` frequently means you end up with client code that does a read/modify/write cycle, with the object acting as dumb data container. It's generally preferable to convert that to a single operation in which the client code describes the desired result, and the object itself does the read/modify/write to achieve that result.
3. Minimize the interface. You should strive for each object to have the smallest interface possible without causing unduly pain for users. Eliminating a public function like `get_n` is nearly always a good thing in itself, independent of its being good for encapsulation.

Since others have commented about `friend` functions, I'll add my two cents worth on that subject as well. It's fairly frequent to hear comments to the effect that "friend should be avoided because it breaks encapsulation."

I must vehemently disagree, and further believe that anybody who thinks that still has some work to do in learning to think like a programmer. A programmer must think in terms of abstractions, and then implement those abstractions as reasonably as possible in the real world.

If an object supports input and/or output, then the input and output are **parts of that object's interface**, and whatever implements that interface is **part of the object**. The *only* other possibility is that the type of object *does not* support input and/or output.

The point here is pretty simple: at least to support the normal conventions, C++ inserters and extractors must be written as free (non-member) functions. Despite this, insertion and extraction are just as much a part of the class' interface as any other operations, and (therefore) the inserter/extractor are just as much a part of the class (as an abstraction) as anything else is.

I'd note for the record that this is part of why I prefer to implement the friend functions involved *inside* the class, as I've shown them above. From a logical viewpoint, they're part of the class, so making them look like part of the class is a good thing.

I'll repeat one last time for emphasis: Giving them access to class internals can't possibly break encapsulation, because in reality they're parts of the class -- and C++'s strange requirement that they be implemented as free functions does not change that fact by one, single, solitary iota.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, it's exactly what I was hoping for. Your points about encapsulation and the general use of friend functions are very clear and helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Use get_n, since this is not a [proper usage of friend](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.2). And if `get_n` is a simple `return n`, the compiler is most likely going to [inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) it automatically.

Comment: -1 for *friends are not OOP friendly*. This is not the case. A popular example are classes with private constructors, that have a factory-class as friends. This is very good object oriented design that relies on friends. A more detailed explanation can be found in the [C++FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.2).

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: This is not the same as that, because the data member is already publicly exposed.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Thanks for the clarification (+1 for I like failing generalizations), and I am aware of usage of *friend* but in this specific question's case, it really is not the solution. I am going to edit my answer to be clearer.

Comment: @DeadMG: I agree, but the answer states it in a very general fashion (saying they *are not OOP friendly*, instead of *they are not appropriate here*), so I felt obligated to contradict.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer your question with a question:

- Why did you create the public `get_n()` in the first place?

Comment: That was a dummy example. I could have a simple container with a private sz member and a size() const public function.

Comment: @Garp: And that was a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the best practice is for the class to implement a `toString` method, that the output operator uses to get a string representation. Since this is a member function, it can access all the data directly. It also has the added benefit that you can make this method `vritual`, so that subclasses can override it, and you only need a single output operator for the base class.

Comment: It already has a `toString` method- the stream insertion operator.

Comment: @DeadMG: The stream-insertion operator is not a method (which to me means the same as *member function*). It always has to be a free function (for user-defined types).

Answer (score 0):

Can the operator be implemented without using `friend`? Yes- don't use `friend`. No- make `friend`.